# Create an img file with Ubuntu hard disk info

Tags: hard-drive, copy, burning, clone

I have installed the latest version of Ubuntu and I've spent about 4 hours installing and customizing software within the OS.
I would like to create an .IMG file that contains the hard disk partition info and all of Ubuntu installation, so basically I would like to create an exact copy of the drive so that I can install this to 5 other machines. Can someone recommend whats the fastest/best option?

Comment: There are loads of scripts that create an ISO files from your installed Ubuntu system (most distros based on Ubuntu have their own even if just forks of a prior one), but we'd just use `dd` to clone one drive and have the output write to 8 drives at once  (assuming 8 drives were inserted) as we did lots (using something like `cat diskimage-16.04-7 | tee >(dd of=/dev/sda) >(dd of=/dev/sdb) >(dd of=/dev/sdc)....`  but the best option is whatever works for you...  (we had a motherboard (box not in a box) that just did the cloning..)

Answer (score 0):

There are loads of scripts that create an ISO files from your installed Ubuntu system (*most distros based on Ubuntu have their own even if just forks of a prior one*)

But in the past at an non-profit, we'd just use `dd` to clone one drive and have the output write to [up-to] 8 drives at once as we did lots of cloning.  These disks would then be installed in a 'being-built' system, booted & tested (with fine tuning if they required additional drives due to nvidia or different cards)

The command was something like

```
cat image-16.04-20161007 | tee >(dd of=/dev/sda) >(dd of=/dev/sdb) .... | dd of=/dev/sdh
```

but the best option is whatever works for you...

*Our cloning was done on a motherboard (box not in a box) that just did the cloning.. when it died, we'd replace it modifying it the number of drives the new 'board' could handle*